# How to launch pgadmin4 and open a sql file in windows cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I would like to be able to open PGadmin4, connect to a server/database and open an sql file using only command line (Windows).

Is there a way to do that ?

Opening pg admin is fairly simple :

```
start "" /B "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe"
```

but I don't seem able to find a way to connect to the appropriate server/database and open the sql file I want

I'm writing a .bat file to automate the initial opening of a bunch of application for a development project (django)

Comment: Well, what does `pgAdmin4.exe` documentation say?

Answer (score -1):

Try running following command:

Connect to a specific database:

**\c database_name**;
For example, the following command connects to the dvdrental database:

**\c dvdrental**;
You are now connected to database "dvdrental" as user "postgres".

For other commands, visit: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cheat-sheet/